"File not found" error when retrieving audio duration with Expo audio on Android
I'm using Expo Audio in my React Native app to record audio. After stopping and unloading the recording properly, I successfully obtain the URI of the recorded audio. However, when I try to get the duration of the audio, it occasionally throws an error saying "File not found" This issue occurs infrequently and seems to happen on Android and iOS devices.
const uri = recording.current.getURI();
await recording.current.stopAndUnloadAsync();

const fileInfo = await Audio.Sound.createAsync({ uri }, { shouldPlay: false }); //error happens here
const duration = fileInfo.status.durationMillis

This is the error details on Android
Error Code: E_LOAD_ERROR
Error Type: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource$FileDataSourceException
Root Cause: java.io.FileNotFoundException
File Path: /data/user/0/package.name/cache/Audio/recording-948f76bb-8ed0-4ab8-ba2e-8fd7509b8583.m4a
Error Message: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

This is the error details on iOS
Error: This media may be damaged. - The AVPlayerItem instance has failed with the error code -11829 and domain "AVFoundationErrorDomain".

Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve it?
Few of our users encountered this problem, and it's happened very rarely for other users as well. The Expo Audio library returns a URI after recording, but when trying to access the file, it throws an error.

Is this happening because of low memory/cache storage limitation? Expo audio saves recorded audio to cache memory in android anyway

Did you get anywhere with this? I'm seeing the same issue: finish a recording, attempt to move it from cache to documents using FileSystem, it throws an error saying the file can't be found.
